# application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: not called iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, launch

I have a trouble when my app is shut down and I start the app by opening from a URL. This is working with iOS 7 and I can perform what I want on launch, but not with iOS 8.

application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: is the method that's not being called properly.

I've checked the device log and I can't see that the method gets called. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: can you check if application:handleOpenURL:  method works

Comment: The same thing, nothing happens.

Comment: This method of only called if you're app is activated from a background state. If you're app is dead, you should look for the info from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Answer (score 5):

Inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` you can extract the URL that the app was opened from,

```
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]
```

Answer (score 0):

The method needs to go in AppDelegate.m and not in your ViewController.m

Comment: Yes, ofc it's in my AppDelegate.m. Solved it, will have to post my answer.

Comment: @Vibbe747 you should post your answer/solution here.